# Connect MSSQL 2008 database to Android Eclipse Emulator?

Tags: android, sql-server, connection

I use Eclipse here is my MainActivity.java codes:

```
package com.example.tutorialsqlserver_android;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    EditText txtErrMsg;
    EditText txtData;   
    Connection connect;


    private Connection CONN( )
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        String errmsg = null;
        txtErrMsg.setText("action");
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.114.1.129/master;user=sa;password=***I now my password thanks***;";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);

        }   

        catch (SQLException se)
        {
            errmsg = se.getMessage() + " " + se.getErrorCode() + " bitti";
            txtErrMsg.setText(errmsg);
            Log.e("ERRO",errmsg);
            return null;
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            errmsg = "B1 " + e.getMessage()  + " " + e.getLocalizedMessage() + " bitti1";
            txtErrMsg.setText(errmsg);
            Log.e("ERRO",errmsg);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errmsg = "B2 " + e.toString() + " bitti2";
            txtErrMsg.setText(errmsg);
            Log.e("ERRO",errmsg);
            return null;
        }

        finally
        {
            txtErrMsg.setText("yemedi ");

        }


        txtErrMsg.setText("OK ");
        return conn;
    }

    public void QuerySQL(String COMANDOSQL)
       { 
           ResultSet rs;
           try
           {
               Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
               rs = statement.executeQuery(COMANDOSQL);

               while(rs.next())
               { 
                   txtData.setText(rs.getString("Name"));
               }

           }

           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Log.e("ERRO",e.getMessage());  
           } 
       }

   @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        txtErrMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtErrMsg);
        txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtData);

        connect =  CONN();
        if(connect != null)
        {
            txtData.setText("OlacakInsallah");
            //QuerySQL("select * from Students");
        }}}
```

I put jtds-1.2.7.jar file under my projects Android Private Libraries>>jtds-1.2.7.jar

And my activity_main.xml codes are below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_conteudo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Metin" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtErrMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_conteudo"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Ilk" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtErrMsg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtErrMsg"
        android:layout_marginTop="143dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My sql version: youUpload.org/fazsgrh
My sql login: youUpload.org/e32xkba

Where is my faulty? Thank you. This application is not working now.

Comment: `This application is not working now.`  Do you think it might be useful to tell us what the problem is?

Comment: Let me explain.This program that I try is about connecting any MSSQL database and get any information in order to see the info on my Android phone screen. That, I couldn't do this so. Here is my application codes, may you help me? [link](we.tl/Fo0SuK5DR2) You can download workspace's project from here: we.tl/Fo0SuK5DR2